# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\sin^2 (n\alpha)} \le 1$? Why?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

In reviewing some old notes of mine, I find the following worked example:

> Let $0<\alpha<1$. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha^n \sin^2 (n\alpha)$
> converge?
>
> Use the root test:  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\alpha^n \sin^2 (n\alpha)} =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha \sqrt[n]{\sin^2 (n\alpha)} \color{red}{\le \alpha} < 1$ so the series converges.

My question concerns the part highlighted in red.  The solution seems to be saying that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\sin^2 (n\alpha)} \le 1$.  I suppose it's obvious that if the limit exists at all, it must be less than or equal to 1, but I don't see any obvious reason why the limit should exist (and indeed my instinct is telling me it shouldn't, except for carefully-chosen special values of $\alpha$).  Any help?

Comment: You are absolutely right that the limit does not need to exist. But root test actually says $\limsup \sqrt[n]{\sin^2(n\alpha)}$ which does exists.

Comment: @JackyChong if you could expand on that for an answer I would be grateful, as it seems to be precisely what I was confused about!

Comment: What do you need me to expand on?

Comment: @JackyChong Honestly it doesn’t even need to be expanded, I’d just like it posted as an answer so I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right that the limit does not need to exist. But root test actually says $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{\sin^2(n\alpha)}$, which does exists.